# Always right click Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, right-click

I have got small code in C# Webdriver framework:

```
drawOnCanvas.ContextClick(element)
                            .MoveToElement(element, 62, 21)
                            .ClickAndHold()
                            .MoveByOffset(155, 195)
                            .MoveByOffset(60, 20)
                            .MoveByOffset(240, 200)
                            .Release()
                            .Build()
                            .Perform();
```

but it always change element by right click and I get Inspect element etc. What I have do to avoid this, make a left click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `ContextClick` method, which will simulate the right mouse button on a Windows machine. Use `Click` instead for a normal left click.